# Removal of Duplicate Values - Leading Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to remove duplicate values from my workbook, but the issue is that the same entries, the one I am attempting to keep has the year leading as seen below.

[image]

I've tried using a VLOOKUP (below) but since it's not a exact match, I used TRUE, which doesn't return the value I really want and it would take another step to remove the value without the leading year.

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,F2:F657,1,TRUE)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Base on your comment below, you only care if the ones without the year exist in one with the year, If so you want to be able to know so you can delete it, If not you want to know so you can keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,F2:F657,1,FALSE),INDEX(F2:F657,MATCH(F2,SUBSTITUTE(F2:F657,LEFT(F2:F657,7),""),0)))}
```

This works as follows: (1) first it checks if the vlookup finds a match. If that's not the case then (2) it will try to find a match in the list by removing the first 7 characters (year + space + hyphen + space). So, the above solution assumes that the first 7 characters must be always remove (this solution is not flexible to the length of the characters that need to be removed).

Furthermore, the above solution assumes that you have an Excel version which knows the formula [IfError](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) (requires Excel 2007+). Otherwise, you can substitute that with a complete `If` formula.

Note, that the above formula needs to be entered as an array formula. So, you need to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to enter the formula. For more information on array formulas have a look at Microsoft's website here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, but the reason I didn't go about it this way is that the values with the leading year are actually the ones I want to keep, but if there is no leading year, I want the one without it. That's where my issue comes about as I can't think of the logic that will allow me to keep the values with leading years and then use the ones without when there is no leading year found.

Comment: Then just invert the above formula and move the second part (with the `index/match`) first and the `vlookup` to the end of the `IfError` formula (like so): `{=IFERROR(INDEX(F2:F657,MATCH(F2,SUBSTITUTE(F2:F657,LEFT(F2:F657,7),""),0)),VLOOKUP(F2,F2:F657,1,FALSE))}`